# Change Collation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, replication, collation

I tried to change collation database like this :

```
ALTER DATABASE [MYDB] 
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
GO 

ALTER DATABASE [MYDB]
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO 

ALTER DATABASE [MYDB] 
SET MULTI_USER; 
GO
```

But I got this error:

> Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 0%.
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   Warning: Changing default collation for database 'MYDB', which is used in replication. All replication databases should have the same default collation.
>
> Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The object 'CK_PriceL_EndDate' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it.
>   Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
>
> Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The object 'CK_PriceL_Price' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
>
> Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The object 'chk_trades_year' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
>
> Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The object 'chk_trades_month' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
>
> Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The object 'SplitObjects' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
>
> Msg 5072, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   ALTER DATABASE failed. The default collation of database 'MYDB' cannot be set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

I read how to set single user to multi user in [doc.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

I read how to set or change the database collation in [doc.microsoft](http://Set%20or%20Change%20the%20Database%20Collation)

Note: this server is main publisher of replication, I use SQL Server 2019

Comment: As per [Set or Change the Column Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation), "_You cannot change the collation of a column that is currently referenced by any one of the following: A computed column; An index; Distribution statistics, either generated automatically or by the CREATE STATISTICS statement; A CHECK constraint; A FOREIGN KEY constraint_"

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, belongs on dba. But changing the **default** collation of a database probably does not do what you think it does. Seems you might need an actual expert to help.

Comment: @smor all data base in replication plan is English collation but this one is arabic, i do not know about this deference. I tried to integrate this one like other database like this action but error say, Changing default collation for database 'MYDB', which is used in replication. All replication databases should have the same default collation. Now, my databases are not same collation and i'm worry about loss data in replication or failure plan. (im sorry my English grammar is horrible)

Comment: @SMor thank you, i tried this question to `dba exchange` . i think this problem made, when install sql server and select wrong collation . i guess, unfortunately  need re-install SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can find answer for change SQL SERVER Collation after installation .

We can run by this bat file for change collation. (Save below code in text and change file type to `.bat`) and then run as administrator.

this file code is very simple :

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER2008\MSSQL\Binn
sqlservr -m -T4022 -T3659 -s"MSSQLServer2008" -q"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
```

This clear anyone need special path and instance name.

Note: This is not a recommended idea for change collation on production servers.

Comment: Yes, because it can delete All entire the database